# How to factorise $x^2 + x - 1$?

Tags: factoring

I was asked to prepare a set of notes for year 12 students. These notes are going to be used by these students to prepare for the examinations. Naturally, I searched for problems to include so the students could get practice and I came across the following problem

> Factorise $7x^2 + 7x - 7$ as far as possible

When making the solutions document I had difficulties in going far "as far as possible". I easily saw that $7(x^2 + x - 1)$ was one possible factorisation, but then I proceeded to see if I could factorise $x^2 + x - 1$ and it was here that I became stuck. I tried using the quadratic formula to find the roots and express $x^2 + x - 1$ as $(x_1 - root1)(x_2 - root2)$, but I couldn't seem to find such an expression. After all of that I used Wolfram Alpha and was given an irreducible factorisation of $-1/4 (-2x + \sqrt{5} -1)(2x + \sqrt{5} + 1)$. I tried to work backwards to see if could come to this factorisation, but either my lack of creativity or my terrible computation skills have left with me no solution.

If I could get a hint (maybe a solution too, but one hidden by spoiler block would be nice just so I can attempt it myself first), I'd be really thankful.

Comment: To *properly* answer we need to know *why* you "couldn't seem to find such an expression", i.e. show us what you did so we can see what went awry. Otherwise we are forced to make (wild) guesses.

Comment: @BillDubuque I didn't know if my idea was leading to my a correct solution (an irreducible factorisation). I looked at wolfram alpha's output and I doubted that I was on the right track. I may have also made some careless errors. A combination of the above I guess would an answer to why I couldn't or rather found it difficult to find a solution

Comment: @BillDubuque I didn't know if my idea was leading to my a correct solution (an irreducible factorisation). I looked at wolfram alpha's output and I doubted that I was on the right track. I may have also made some careless errors. A combination of the above I guess would an answer to why I couldn't or rather found it difficult to find a solution

Comment: It's still not clear why you couldn't compute the factorization using the quadratic formula. Precisely where did you have problems doing so?

Comment: @BillDubuque I arrived at the answer Stack posted, but where I got stuck was factorising as far as possible. I wanted to try and arrive at the same solution wolfram alpha returned

Comment: Do you meam this: $\,(-1/4)(-2x +a)(2x+b) = (x-a/2)(x+b/2)$? That follows by writing $\,-1/4 = (-1/2)(1/2)\,$ and distributing the $-1/2$ into $-2x+a$ and the $1/2$ into $2x+b,\,$ or, equivalently pulling a factor of $-2$ and $2$ out of each, with the goal to make the leading coef $=1$ in each linear factor. If you had shown your work we could have narrowed that down quite quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use the quadratic formula or complete the square.  The quadratic formula gives you the roots directly.  If you don't know it, write
$$
    \begin {align}
        x^2+x-1&=\left(x^2+x+\frac 14\right)-\frac 54\\
        &=\left(x+\frac 12\right)^2-\frac 54\\
        &=\left(x+\frac 12+\frac {\sqrt 5}2\right)\left(x+\frac 12-\frac {\sqrt 5}2\right)
    \end {align}
$$
where you can combine the fractions if you want.  From the second to the third line is seeing the difference of squares.

Comment: This is quite a pretty solution. Thanks Ross. I remember similar problems where such a trick worked wonders. I guess I needed a break because I saw the solution so quickly afterwards

Comment: The quadratic formula is derived in exactly this manner.  It is essentially a generic completion of the square.   Of course sometimes the roots are complex.

Comment: I do remember that. This reminds me that you can learn a good deal from proofs.

Comment: @BillDubuque:  No worries.

Answer (score 3):

> I tried using the quadratic formula to find the roots and express $x^2 + x - 1$ as $(x_1 - root1)(x_2 - root2)$, but I couldn't seem to find such an expression.

That's a good idea; perhaps something went wrong when finding those roots?

Carefully use the quadratic formule for the roots of $\color{red}{a}x^2 + \color{blue}{b}x + \color{green}{c}$, so:

$$\color{red}{1}x^2 + \color{blue}{1}x \color{green}{-1} = 0 \iff x = \frac{- \color{blue}{1} \pm \sqrt{\color{blue}{1}^2-4 \cdot \color{red}{1} \cdot (\color{green}{-1}})}{2\cdot\color{red}{1}}=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$$
So:
$$x^2 + x - 1=\left(x-\left(\frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\right)\left(x-\left(\frac{-1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\right)$$
You could rewrite/simplify this further to see it matches WolframAlpha's answer.

Comment: Who is down-voting this (and the other) answer(s); and, more importantly, what for...?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: I managed to get it after a small break

Comment: You're welcome and well done.

Answer (score 1):

Write your equation as
$$x^2 + x -1 = (Ax+B)(Cx+D)$$
for some real numbers $A,B,C,D$. Multiplying out the right side, we find that
$$x^2+x-1 = ACx^2 + (BC + AD)x - AC$$
This implies that $AC = 1$, $BC + AD = 1$, and $BD = -1$. You can solve this system to return some desired values.